# Access 2013 form colouring issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Super basic question, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

[image: Horrible colour]

How do I change this horrible yellow colour that access defaults to when highlighting which row/column your selected data is in? I've fiddled with literally every colour option I can find in the form properties and have had no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a form, it's a datasheet (or a form in datasheet view). They just look like that, I'm pretty sure that color isn't configurable.

Comment: I believe Andre is right. This is not controlled by any of the Form.DatasheetXXXX settings or the Themes as far as I can see.

Comment: If you need full control over colors and behavior, use continuous form instead of datasheet. But you won't be able to resize and move columns and quick filtering will be more limited

Comment: Thanks for the help! Had a feeling it couldn't be changed.